# Spring MVC: The stylesheet not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc, resources

I'm having issues getting my css sheets to load in the browser for my spring webapp - I keep getting the following error:

> The stylesheet http://localhost:8080/MyBudget/resources/css/hello.css
>   was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

[File Strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU0tt.png)

In my web.xml file, I have specified my resources as following;

```
 <mvc:resources location="/resources/core/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

In my view (.JSP), I'm referencing the css file as following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="<c:url value="/resources/css/hello.css"/>" type="text/css" />
```

I have tried just about everything to get this to work, and nothing - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thats coused by mvc configuration I think,
are you using load and startup configuraiton ?
I had same problem I solved by

```
spring.mvc.servlet.load-on-startup=1
```

to add my application.properties file

I read from here

https://www.javatpoint.com/load-on-startup